# Can different smart pointers refer to the same object?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

It's possible to have weak_ptr along with shared_ptr. But I wanted to know if it is possible to create a shared_ptr and unique_pointer referencing to the same object. If yes, which rule has to be followed ?

Comment: It can, but then it would be bad.. and there is no point of using smart pointers then.

Comment: The very idea of more than *the* unique pointer referencing an object is somewhat counter-intuitive to the very name prefix: *unique*. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: We were just studying, the question came to our minds, we didn't find an answer to it :)

Comment: Well, what does your destroyer do?  Both `unique` and `shared` support custom destroyers.  If they both `delete`, see below.  If not?  Well, something different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create a `unique_ptr` and a `shared_ptr` to the same object, they will not know about each other.  Therefore, you will end up with a "double free" error, not to mention that you might inadvertently dereference one pointer when the other one has already been freed.

In short, don't do it.  If you need to transfer ownership from a unique_ptr to a shared_ptr or vice versa, call `release()` on the "old" pointer when you create the "new" one.

To your question about "which rule will be followed," the answer is both.  Each smart pointer will follow its own rules, but the overall system behavior will be erroneous.  The same as if you create a single smart pointer from a raw pointer before or after calling `delete` yourself.

Note that the same advice applies to creating two `unique_ptr`s or two `shared_ptr`s to the same raw pointer.  The fact that you're mixing types of smart pointers is not really relevant.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that 2 `shared_ptr` s will know about each other as they will share ownership of the same object. If this is the case, you will not have a "double free" error and will not accidentally dereference one pointer when another has been freed. Only when the last `shared_ptr` with ownership goes out of scope will the object be freed.

Comment: @Ninja: That is only true *if* the two `shared_ptr`s know about each other.  That will be the case if you create one from the other, or if you use `enable_shared_from_this`.  But if they are both created from the same raw pointer, they will not know about each other, and double free will be the result.